# Parent id returns 1 after using fork

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, fork

I am confused about the output of following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   pid_t childpid = 0;
   int i, n;
   if (argc != 2){   /* check for valid number of command-line arguments */
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
       return 1;
   }
   n = atoi(argv[1]);
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
   if ((childpid = fork()))
       break;
   fprintf(stderr,"i:%d  process ID:%ld  parent ID:%ld  child ID:%ld\n",
       i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)childpid);
   return 0; 
}
```

output after run it with command argument n = 3:

```
i:1  process ID:3662  parent ID:2658  child ID:3663
i:2  process ID:3663  parent ID:1  child ID:3664
i:3  process ID:3664  parent ID:1  child ID:0
```

I wonder why parent ID is always 1, and after I changed last line of code to 
printf instead of fprintf, the parent ID only contains 1 occasionally. This is 
an example in a textbook - Unix System Programming.

Comment: there is a logic error in the posted code.  this line `for (i = 1; i < n; i++)` should be: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: @user3629249 This is an example code in the textbook. This is how they presented in the textbook. I don't think it matters though.

Comment: yeah it doesn't matter, Are you able to debug it? placing the arguments you are sending to fprintf into temp variables and seeing what they are in the debugger?

Comment: @matt Yes. I named it forkexp.c. Run it with ./forkexp 3

Comment: sorry yeah, realized you said in the question

Comment: if you pass a command line parameter of `3`, then you expect 3 child processes to be created.   if we plug `3` in for `n` the successive passes through the loop have `i` =1  then `i` = 2` the loop exits because i=3 is not < 3  So it matters a lot how that `for()` statement is written

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, I understand that, I said it doesn't matter because it will not affect the question I asked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the children are getting to the `fprintf()`, the parent process may have already exited, causing the child processes to be reparented to init (which has PID 1).

Adding a `sleep(1)` before `return 0` will probably fix this.

Comment: Yes! you are right, thanks! I just start to learn os, do not know there is a sleep function. It makes much more sense.

Comment: using `sleep()` to wait for a child process!  a very poor idea,  the code should actually wait on the pid of the child.  one of the better ways to wait on the child is via the `waitpid()` function

Comment: @user3629249 While that's true, `sleep(1)` is sufficient here, and it's a heck of a lot easier to explain why it works.

Answer (score 0):

when calling `fork()`  there are 3 kinds of returned values.

```
-1 when the `fork()` failed to create a child process
0 when the current process is the child
>0 when the current process is the parent.
```

the posted code is exiting the loop when either the `fork()` returned an error indication or in the parent process.

Other wise, in the child process and the child goes around the loop trying to create a childs' child.

the parent should be creating all the children and waiting for the children to complete/exit before the parent exits.

( `waitpid()` is a good method for the parent to wait for the child )

Note: killing the parent of a child before the child is exited can result in either of three conditions (depends on the specific OS) either the child becomes a zombie or the child becomes a child of process 1 or the child gets a signal and exits

here is an example of how to write the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n;

    if (argc != 2)
    {   /* check for valid number of command-line arguments */
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Number of child processes to create>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of arguments

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    pid_t childpid[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        switch( childpid[i] = fork() )
        {
           case -1:
                // handle fork failure
                perror( "fork failed" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                break;

            case 0:
                // handle child
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "i:%d  CHILD process ID:%ld  PARENT process ID:%ld\n",
                         i,
                         (long)getpid(),
                         (long)getppid());
                exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
                break;

            default:
                // handle parent
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "i:%d  PARENT process ID:%ld  CHILD process ID:%ld\n",
                         i,
                         (long)getpid(),
                         (long)childpid[i]);
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end for

    for( i=0; i<n; i++ )
    {
        waitpid( childpid[i], NULL, 0 );
    }

   return 0;
} // end function: main
```

an example output is: when the command line parameter is `3`

```
i:0  PARENT process ID:918  CHILD process ID:919
i:1  PARENT process ID:918  CHILD process ID:920
i:0  CHILD process ID:919  PARENT process ID:918
i:1  CHILD process ID:920  PARENT process ID:918
i:2  PARENT process ID:918  CHILD process ID:921
i:2  CHILD process ID:921  PARENT process ID:918
```